# Symfony 3 FormType - Entity through options array

Tags: php, arrays, forms, symfony, entity

I would like to know how to pass my entity correctly and another variable in my createForm function ?

Let me explain, I would like to do this:

```
$repo = $em->getRepository('ProjectBundle:Organisation\Organisation');
            $list = $repo->children($this->getUser()->getOrganisation());
            $form = $this->createForm('ProjectBundle\Form\Robot\RobotType', array($entity,$list));
```

I need to pass to my FormType another variable, so I use a array directly.

My FormType:

```
<?php

namespace ProjectBundle\Form\Robot;

use ProjectBundle\Entity\Robot\Robot;
use ProjectBundle\Form\User\UserType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class RobotType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('serial_number')
            ->add('shell_color',ChoiceType::class,array(
                'choices' => Robot::getArrayShellColor()
            ))
            ->add('tray1Color',ChoiceType::class,array(
                'choices' => Robot::getTrayColor()
            ))
            ->add('tray2Color',ChoiceType::class,array(
                'choices' => Robot::getTrayColor()
            ))
            ->add('tray3Color',ChoiceType::class,array(
                'choices' => Robot::getTrayColor()
            ))
            ->add('hasBattery')
            ->add('volume')
            ->add('organisation',null,array('choices' => $options['data'][1]));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'ProjectBundle\Entity\Robot\Robot'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'projectbundle_robot_new';
    }


}
```

Here I need to get my variable $list, for the organisation field, so it's `$options['data'][1]`.

But I have a mistake, which I understand but I do not know how to correct:

```
The form's view data is expected to be an instance of class ProjectBundle\Entity\Robot\Robot, but is a(n) array. You can avoid this error by setting the "data_class" option to null or by adding a view transformer that transforms a(n) array to an instance of ProjectBundle\Entity\Robot\Robot.
```

This is normal because now I pass it in an array, it's my variable `$options['data'][0]` that contains my object now.

How to do ?
Thank you

Comment: Check EntityType and the parameter query_builder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass ProjectBundle\Entity\Robot\Robot entity to the createForm method as a second parameter and an options array as a third parameter.

```
$form = $this->createForm('ProjectBundle\Form\Robot\RobotType', $entity, array($list));
```